# Difference Quotient with $x-a$

Tags: calculus

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm having trouble understanding how to do the step highlighted in red if anyone could help

Comment: Factor $(x-a)$ in the numerator.

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images but instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: This is the distributive property $xy + xz = x(y + z)$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, that one is: $\dfrac{-2(x-a) - 1(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a}= \dfrac{-2(x-a)}{x-a} - \dfrac{1(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a} = -2 -1(x+a)= -2 -(x +a)=-2-x-a$ where we used the property fraction subtraction with the common denominator and the multiplicative identity property of the reals, namely:  $\dfrac{x-y}{z} = \dfrac{x}{z}-\dfrac{y}{z}$, and $1\cdot x = x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the distributive property xy+xz=x(y+z)

was what I was looking for, thank you.